# What is a good build system for Angular2 projects?

Tags: angular, build, gruntjs, gulp

Me and my team recently shifted to Angular2 (or AngularJS 2) from AngularJS 1.x. We used to use **Yeoman Angular Generator** for scaffolding and `grunt` for building and creating a war using the inbuilt *gruntfile.js* that used to get created by default with the above mentioned generator. We used it by making some minor changes to it and we were good to go.
What this file essentially does is:

- It combines all third party dependency js files installed from *package.json* in *node_modules* folder (i.e. `npm install`) & optionally even from *bower.json* in *bower_components* folder(i.e. `bower install`) [if you are using it] into a single *vendor.js* file (Does so by doing concatenation, minification and uglification)
- It repeats the above steps for css files and combines it into *vendor.css*
- It combines all user javascript files into *scripts.js* and css files in *styles.css*
- In bundles these 4 files with *index.html* and other necessary things like images, fonts, etc.

I have been looking for a similar solution for Angular2 but have failed so far. I tried using `gulp` by using *gulpfile.js* found in **angular2-seed project** or `ng build` from **angular-cli project**  but none have provided such a solution. 
The problem always occurs with the node_modules folder. The typescript *ts* files from these folders which are completely unnecessary get built into the bundle.

Now I do understand that Angular2 is different from Angular1 and all but how can build a good build by in this? What approach should I take? And can I achieve anything like what I used to get in Angular1?

Comment: Are you using pure JS? Or TypeScript?

Comment: I am using Typescript

Comment: Have you read this blog post? http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/12/24/creating-an-angular-2-build.html 

He uses ECMA 6 setup for the gulp. And it look like you can take your former gulp config and just paste?

Comment: @McBoman, my former config was grunt based not gulp and it has no way to deal with Typescript so I can't use it.. The blog seems to be good.. Going through it now

Comment: I will just write you a gulp file for css and ts. Are you using any SASS or LESS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you use gulp which is a fantastic tool if you ask me :-) then this setup for a gulp file would work.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const del = require('del');
const typescript = require('gulp-typescript');
const tscConfig = require('./tsconfig.json');
const bower = require('gulp-bower');

/*
    Clean current builds
*/
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  return del('dist/**/*');
});

/*
    Pull in bower dependencies.
    Uses default .bowerrc path
*/
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return bower();
});

//Use custom path
/*
gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return bower('./my_bower_components')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib/'))
});
*/

/*
    Minify css
    Remember to edit distination path
*/
gulp.task('minify-css', function() {
    return gulp.src('styles/*.css')
        .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}, function(details) {
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); // Here
});


/*
    Typescript compile
    Remember to edit distination path
*/
gulp.task('compile', ['clean'], function () {
  return gulp
    .src('app/**/*.ts')
    .pipe(typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/app')); // Here
});

gulp.task('build', ['compile', 'minify-css', 'bower']);
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

**OBS!**

Remember to edit the destination paths.

I have just added bower handling. But when it comes to node modules, you just need to keep your package.json file and then run a npm install when modules are needed.

To bundle all node modules and bower components will you need the gulp bundle kit.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-bundle-assets

Comment: Hi McBoman, How are we dealing with node_modules in this case?

Comment: Are you thinking about installing all the npm packages from your package.json?

Comment: Read the edit under the OBS sign. Hope that can help.

Comment: Running npm install is fine, but I am not able to handle them in the build. The node_modules directory gets copied as is!

Comment: sorry I am out of office for some work. Will try this as soon as possible and update you with this.

Comment: @ashhem did you find a result or ?

Comment: Hey man! Super sorry about the extreme late reply. Have been busy with other projects! But thanks!!! It worked!